# How to solve Active record error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to list properties by joining the venue categories table

THis is my active record.

`@properties = Property.where(:status=>'1')
@properties = @properties.joins(:venue_categories).where("venue_categories.id=?", params[:venue_categories]).all if params[:venue_categories].present?`

when i tried this i am got my sql error "operand should contain 1 column(s)

Any help is appreciatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@properties = Property.where(:status=>'1')
@properties = @properties.joins(:venue_categories).where(venue_categories: {id: params[:venue_categories]}) if params[:venue_categories].present?
```